# Sentiment analysis in a generic text with Transformers

Tags: deep-learning, sentiment-analysis, text-classification, bert-language-model, transformer-model

Is it correct to use BERT (or any other Transformers-based model) finetuned with a dataset like IMDb if I want to do sentiment analysis in a generic text (unrelated with movies)?

If not, how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

No, because the domain of the training data (IMDB reviews) is different from the domain that you want to evaluate on. This violates one of the main assumptions for machine learning, namely that the training data and the test/production data are from the same distribution.

What you could do is called "domain adaptation", since you want to perform the same task on a different domain. But for this, you need labeled data, i.e. for each text you need to have a label "positive"/"negative"/...